# Graphing values generated from loop

Tags: python

I have a Catalan series generated with a loop and i need to graph it but do not know how to do so. I want to make a bar chart with the values generated along with the value n. 
Here is the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from pylab import *


def Catalan(n):
    if n==0:
        return (1)
    elif n==1:
        return (1)
    else:
        return (((4*n-2)*Catalan(n-1))/(n+1))
for n in range(18):
    print (Catalan(n))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is pretty simple. Sorry, at first I didn't notice you wanted a bar chart. I have updated my answer:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pylab as pl


def Catalan(n):
    if n==0:
        return (1)
    elif n==1:
        return (1)
    else:
        return (((4*n-2)*Catalan(n-1))/(n+1))
result = [Catalan(n) for n in range(18)]
ax = pl.subplot()
ax.bar(range(len(result)), result)
pl.show()
```

[image: figure 1]

If true, `log` sets the axis to be log scale:

```
ax.bar(range(len(result)), result, log=True)
```

[image: figure 2]

Comment: This is very good, but the series grows exponentially - changing to `ax.bar(range(len(result)), result, log=True)` (making the y-axis log-scaled) would give more insight.

Comment: @HughBothwell I have appended my answer with your suggestion